# New column added to content type - not appearing on an item of that type

Tags: content-type, site-column

As title says, I have added a Site Column to an extisting Site Content Type. When looking at an item (it happens to be a page) that is of that content type, I can't see the new field. By 'looking at', I'm checking through the OOTB 'View Properties' dialog.

Any idea why this content type may not be updating?

Is there a timer job that is responsible for this?

Note: This site does not use a content type hub of any sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed and added through PowerShell - still don't understand why it wasn't working:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-add-the-existing-site-column-to-the-content-type-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Really?  Is this the only way?  Remove the content type and add it again?  Will I lose data already existing in the list(s)?

Comment: I tried to delete it from the UI, but "Sorry, something went wrong; Content Type is still in use".  I'll try it from powershell and see if the data is retained.

Comment: Nah, the script in the link is how to add an existing site column to a content type.  The column already exists in the content type - why would you add it?

Comment: And if you are doing this in Sharepoint Online, just FYI, you can't use `get-spsite` - but the question wasn't tagged with a version.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do SPContentType.Update(true) or 
go to site content type and select your content type -> Advanced Setttings and select 'update all content types inheriting' and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the Site Column in the Content Type is set to hidden? That would explain why it's not visible in forms.